# Pusher Private Channel Subscription Succeeded Callback Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, publish-subscribe, pusher

I am trying to get the data sent back from the server, after connecting to a private Pusher channel. The following code works for a presence channel:

```
this.presenceChannel = this.pusher.subscribe('presence-chat');

this.presenceChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(data){

   //I can access all of the data here as expected
   console.log(data);

});
```

But when I try the same approach with a private channel:

```
this.privateChannel = this.pusher.subscribe('private-user');

this.privateChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(data){

    //This returns an empty Object {}
    console.log(data);

});
```

The interesting thing is, in the POST request data I can see the data that I am trying to access, but I can't figure out why I can't access it like I can for presence channels:

```
{"auth":"a146722cb55df886314f:7326fb3e1c807a679b4d4d5e5742fddc121d5ec18f5f078d054962b0267972a4","channel_data"
:"{\"data\":\"test\"}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

try binding to this event instead

```
'pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded'
```

The pusher:subscription_succeeded event is triggered following the receipt of a pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded event. The different event name is used to differentiate a public event from an internal one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but seem this event doesn't get fired for me when I bind to it.